# How can Elisp code determine the previously selected window?

Tags: window, selected-window

I would like to implement an interactive function that, in the "canonical" case, selects the window that was selected before the currently selected one<sup>1</sup>.

But my plan founders immediately on this question: how can my future function find out, to begin with, what the previously selected window is???

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> There are a few edge cases, e.g. when no other window was previously selected, that I won't get into.</sup>

Comment: `C-h i g(elisp)Selecting windows` has some information that might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Emacs 27.1, the previously selected window is recorded and can be obtained with [`old-selected-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html#index-old_002dselected_002dwindow). The previously selected window in each frame can be obtained with [`frame-old-selected-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html#index-frame_002dold_002dselected_002dwindow). If you want older information, you can record it with a hook in [`window-selection-change-functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html#index-window_002dselection_002dchange_002dfunctions).

In older versions of Emacs, I don't think Emacs remembers any historical information about window selections by default, and there's no hook for window selection. You would have to advise at least `select-window`, and quite possibly other built-in functions that change the window selection.